# Trying to make one file out of many Hillshade files

Tags: convert, merge, hillshade

I am trying to make a hilshade file for all of Colorado but when I download the DEM data for the state there are over 25 files. I have converted them all to hillsahde, but now I want to work with just one file instead of 25 of them.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour].  What GIS software are you using?  Please provide details of that as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: You need to mosaic first, hillshade last, for otherwise the state will be interlaced with edge artifacts.  See http://www.quantdec.com/SYSEN597/GTKAV/section9/chapter_29d.htm#hillshading for step-by-step instructions.